# Alternate phrase for "circle jerk."

Tags: single-word-requests

Crass as it may be I have to find a suitable alternative to "circle jerk" which describes a situation in which everyone agrees about some subject but still love getting worked up about it and feed off each other's passion.  I have heard of "echo chamber" but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: How about "talk radio"?

Comment: If the answers in the post marked by @hank do not serve, you should explain why not, or your question will probably get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Ignore me. I am obviously still asleep, but can't delete my posted answer.